# Iterate through discussion list

Tags: object-model, discussion-board

I have SharePoint 2007 discussion list. I want to iterate over all items in the list, so I do the following:

```
var list = web.Lists["discussion"];
var listItems = list.Items;
foreach (var listItem in ListItems)
{
    // do something
}
```

However the iteration doesn't seem to work. The Items collection is always empty. Interesting to notice

```
list.ItemCount
```

will return "4", whereas

```
list.Items.Count
```

will return "0".

Has anyone encounterd such a problem before? I tried another list (custom list), and there I can iterate just fine. Seems to be specific to the discussion-list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the trick is to use `list.Folders`:

```
foreach (SPListItem folder in myDiscussionList.Folders)
{
    // do something
}
```

Source: [How to Read All Discussions and Replies](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/92603d9f-4a96-4236-bc07-78295a81b574)

Comment: +1, but I'd like to add: the point here is that SPList.ItemCount returns number of items including folders, meanwhile SPListItemCollection.Count does not include folder count. The source (*Remarks* section): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.itemcount.aspx

Comment: That link you provided is ... well I don't like it. btw @omlin that +1 is mine, so where is yours :)

Comment: Oops... I confess, but actually, I'm not a greedy person, just immensely exhausted and almost sleeping.. :( Rough day at work. Fixed.

Comment: That worked! How should one know, that discussions are folders and not items? Who would have thought of that?!

Comment: How can I allow a user to click a button to like a discussion list item using c#?

Answer (score 4):

Here is my answer to somewhat similar question. It is 2010 solution in Powershell but you can easily convert it [Moving a Discussion from a Discussion Board to another?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/moving-a-discussion-from-a-discussion-board-to-another/17690#17690)

**Addition:**

I posted my original answer from my mobile device so I feel obligated to provide more info.

To simplify things: In discussion list discussions are folders and messages are items inside folders. Since there are no items on 'root' list.Items.Count will return 0 and list.ItemCount will return number of folders/discussions.

And now the fun stuff.

Get all discussions (@KitMenke already provided this)

```
foreach (SPListItem discussion in list.Folders)
{

}
```

Get all discussions with all messages

```
foreach (SPListItem discussion in list.Folders)
{
    //discussion.Title is discussion title
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    query.Folder = discussion.Folder;
    SPListItemCollection messages = list.GetItems(query);
    foreach(SPListItem message in messages)
    {
        // message["TrimmedBody"] is message body
    }
}
```

Get all messages

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
SPListItemCollection messages = list.GetItems(query);
foreach (SPListItem message3 in messages3)
{
    // message.DisplayName is discussion title !
    // message["TrimmedBody"] is message body
}
```

Get all messages from current user

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Author'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value></Eq>";
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
SPListItemCollection messages = list.GetItems(query);
foreach (SPListItem message in messages)
{
    // message.DisplayName is discussion title !
    // message["TrimmedBody"] is message body
}
```

Comment: +1 for the "Addition" part. It could be fairly useful to have these ready-to-use code snippets in sight when working with Discussion Boards.

Comment: +1 very nice. You have both powershell and object model covered! I removed the 2007 tag from the question because it should be the same.