# Creating discussion-forum using code

Tags: error, discussion-board

I wrote a little utility, which let's me import discussions from a different forum into SharePoint 2010. So far so good. It passed the "works on my machine" test successfully. Unfortunate I cannot say this about the client's machine.

For some very strange reason all discussions as well as all replies are being imported, but the ItemCount of the discussion stays at 0.

Looking at the ULS doesn't reveal any problems.

Has anyone any kind of hint?

Comment: Just curious.. if everything is being imported, why does the ItemCount matter? Not saying it isn't a problem... ;)

Comment: I am not really sure what your problem is but here you can find some info on discussions and ItemCount http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20216/iterate-through-discussion-list/20218#20218

Comment: Can you please the code for the utility you had creted for Importing Discussion threads with replies. Thanx in advance..!!! Thanks
Yatharth
yatharth.arya@gmail.com

Comment: Sorry for taking so long ... I wrote a small [blog-bost](http://www.eiben.weite-welt.com/2012/04/populating-sharepoint-discussion-boards-using-code) containing a sample on how to create threads and replies in code.