# How to make discussion board management view link to response thread?

Tags: sharepoint-online, discussion-board

From subject view:

[image]

If I click the title hyperlink it takes me to the response thread here:

[image]

But I created a new view based off the management view, and I want it to be simple to click the item and have it take you to the response thread.

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

But if you click those titles it takes you to a list view of the responses, not the reply thread. To get to the reply thread you need to right-click, click view item, then in the dialog that opens, click open.

Under the settings for Modify View, there are the column options:

- Subject (linked to item with edit menu)
- Subject (linked to item with
  edit menu) (old)
- Subject (linked to item)
- Type (icon linked to
  document)

But unfortunately none of them link where I want to go.

Is there a way to streamline this to link directly to the response thread?

Answer (score 0):

1. One way is to create calculated column and construct that view URL. Tried this on my environment and it worked. Disadvantage is, we wont get ready made hyperlink and needs to copy that ugly URL. Calculated column formula will be :

   `=CONCATENATE("path1", [Subject], "path2")`

   Path1 and path 2 will be specific to your environment and you can get these by clicking on TITLE field from default view of board (response view page URL)
2. If you must get ready made good looking URL, then you can take help of sharepoint designer customize this management view (or insert new dataview webpart) and here you can put hyperlink on any custom column.
3. Create Custom Column "Responses" of Type Hyperlink. Now create SharePoint designer workflow on Item Created and update current item responses with the correct URL i.e. combination of string and discussion subject . Then add this custom column in your management view.
   somehow there is linking between these views, which work's at run-time. so modifying views wont work.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can you go into more detail regarding version 2. I have sharepoint designer but I can't find how to make a hyperlink column in the view.

Comment: I tested second scenario in my machine and it worked. Though I am redirecting user to response view on title click (2nd screen from your Q). 1. Open site in designer.2. Edit custom view page  2. Remove exiting webpart and insert "Empty dataview" 3. Add relevant fields e.g. Title, Body 4. Now add hyperlink for Title column ..  <td class="ms-vb"><a href="{concat('https:sitename/sites/WFMGR/Lists/board/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FWFMGR%2FLists%2Fboard%2F',@Title,'&amp;FolderCTID=0x01200200F6D092B4566DFE4E9676E4E156577DB6')}">
       <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>

   </a>
   </td>

Comment: Have added third scenario as well..looks more promising. You need to have designer workflow knowledge.

Comment: I'm still trying the second scenario. I created an empty dataview, but I still don't understand where I can add the hyperlink column.

Comment: you just need to add Subject/Title column and put hyperlink for that in code view . Then for href attribute use concatenation. Unfortunately , I am unable to put screenshots (Due to company internet policy)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in management view on Discussion List. When you click on the Title link, it goes to the reply screen, and does not show the original post. 
I went with option 3 of the scenarios, and created a workflow to set the link using instructions from http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=196.

A weird anomaly is that there is no "Title". There are several "Subject" fields, so you hope you pick the right one. It functions, but the anomaly is that if someone creates a topic with the exact same name as another topic, it will append a number to the back of the URL, and puts it in the title. e.g. Discussion Item 1763. Not the hugest inconvenience, but strange.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and i solved it by changing the view. As the discussion has sort of 2 levels. Modify the view from where you'd like to go to the issue and then:

Got the "folders" section and change the view to top-level
[image]

If you have show view in all folders, then you almost never find your way back to actually answering to a post..

I actually find the views of the discussion very confusing

Answer (score 0):

To anyone struggling to reach to Discussion by clicking on title of discussion board in management view. There is just a simple setting to achieve this. In modify view (view you are modifying) , scroll down to Folder options and make settings as.

Folder or flat -> Select Show item inside folder

Show this view -> In top level folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue. It was the Flat.aspx page that was corrupted and had to delete the Flat view and re-create it again and that fixed the issue.

## Resolution:

1. Delete the Flat view : Settings >  Discussion Board Settings
2. Click on Flat under Views
3. Click on Delete button (make sure to note all setting in that page)
4. Create a new view and choose Flat View Format.
5. Type Flat under View Name and check Make this the default view and click OK
   o   Marked as answer by Yassar Wednesday, August 19, 2009 9:05 PM

WARNING - The above is incorrect.  Do not delete your Flat View because you will not be able to create a new one.  I just spent 3 hours recovering from this disaster!
[Moving a Discussion from a Discussion Board to another?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/moving-a-discussion-from-a-discussion-board-to-another)